# How to process differently absent properties and null properties, in Jackson?

Tags: json, kotlin, jackson, null

Let's assume I have the following definitions

```kotlin
data class Patch<out T>(val value:T)
data class MyPatch(val string:Patch<String?>?)
```

I want the following JSON

```json
{}
```

to deserialize to and serialize from:

```kotlin
MyPatch(null)
```

I want the following JSON

```json
{
 "string":null
}
```

to deserialize to and serialize from:

```kotlin
MyPatch(Patch(null))
```

I think it all comes down to the way Jackson manages absent properties, and (json)null values.

I was expecting that the NullNode and the null were treated differently.